# custom config xml setting and storing into dictionary object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-config

I plan to set up configuration keys for FormFields, QueryString parameters etc. In my web.config I have setting as follows:

```
<WhiteListPaametersGroup>
  <WhiteListPaameters>
    <FormField1>EVENTVALIDATION</FormField1>
    <FormField2>VIEWSTATE</FormField2>
    <FormField3>Button1</FormField3>

    <QueryString1>firstname</QueryString1>
    <QueryString2>lastname</QueryString2>

  </WhiteListPaameters>
</WhiteListPaametersGroup>
```

Then in my code, I read the value as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach (XmlNode n in section.ChildNodes)
{
    parameters.Add(n.Name, n.InnerText);
}
```

Is there a better way of storing this. Later on, I want to be able to go through dictionary like object, and be able to get settings for FormFields, Querystrings etc.

Please let me know if I could write it cleaner.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using vs2010, look at this extension, its amazing: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/def289f1-377d-4cd0-802a-80c8be8b6758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML serialization to store your settings and restore them directly into an object. It's not perfect but very easy to set up and gives you object save/restore.

Have this class (properties must be public):

```
public class WhiteListParameters
{
    public string FormField1 { get; set; }
    public string FormField2 { get; set; }
    public string FormField3 { get; set; }

    public string QueryString1 { get; set; }
    public string QueryString2 { get; set; }
}
```

To save it to XML file run this code:

```
WhiteListParameters parms = new WhiteListParameters
                                {
                                    FormField1 = "EVENTVALIDATION",
                                    FormField2 = "VIEWSTATE",
                                    FormField3 = "Button1",
                                    QueryString1 = "firstname",
                                    QueryString2 = "lastname"
                                };

using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\config.xml"))
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (WhiteListParameters));
    xs.Serialize(sw, parms);
    sw.Close();
}
```

To read it back into an object:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\temp\\config.xml"))
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (WhiteListParameters));
    WhiteListParameters parms = (WhiteListParameters) xs.Deserialize(sr);
    sr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you might look into is creating a custom configuration section, which you can register in the `web.config`.

Here's a configuration section that I created for referencing our XSLT templates:

```
namespace Foo.Web.Applications.CustomConfigurationSections
{
    public class XslTemplateConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("xslTemplates")]
        public XslTemplateElementCollection XslTemplates
        {
            get { return this["xslTemplates"] as XslTemplateElementCollection; }
        }
    }

    public class XslTemplateElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this["name"] as string; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("path", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Path
        {
            get { return this["path"] as string; }
            set { this["path"] = value; }
        }
    }

    public class XslTemplateElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public XslTemplateElement this[object key]
        {
            get { return base.BaseGet(key) as XslTemplateElement; }
        }

        public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
        {
            get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap; }
        }

        protected override string ElementName
        {
            get { return "xslTemplate"; }
        }

        protected override bool IsElementName(string elementName)
        {
            bool isName = false;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(elementName))
                isName = elementName.Equals("xslTemplate");
            return isName;
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new XslTemplateElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((XslTemplateElement)element).Name;
        }
    }
}
```

You can register this section in the web.config as follows:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="xslTemplateConfiguration" type="Foo.Web.Applications.CustomConfigurationSections.XslTemplateConfiguration"/>
</configSections>
```

And you can access the collection in your code like this:

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
if (config.HasFile)
{
    var templates = config.GetSection("xslTemplateConfiguration") as XslTemplateConfiguration;
    if (templates != null)
    {
        var templatePath = templates.XslTemplates["PO"].Path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading configuration, .NET Framework has many classes in [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx) namespace. The most important classes are [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) and [ConfigurationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.aspx). Derive from these classes, add properties you want and decorate them with [ConfigurationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationpropertyattribute.aspx) attribute. Advantage of this approach is type-safety, possibility to define list of valid and the fact, that .NET Framework framework will do all reading, parsing and checking of values from web.config for you automatically.